# Demux video and KLV data from MPEG-TS stream, in sync

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, mpeg2-ts, klvdata, stanag

I need to demux the video frames and KLV data from an MPEG-TS stream in sync, frame-by-frame.
The following command to demux the KLV data and outputs a text file with the KLV data.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="some_file.ts" ! tsdemux name=demux \
demux. ! queue ! meta/x-klv ! filesink location="some_file-KLV.txt"
```

The following command to demux the video and outputs a video file.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="some_file.ts" ! tsdemux name=demux \
demux. ! queue ! decodebin ! videorate ! videoscale ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location="some_file-video.mp4"
```

On combining the above two:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="some_file.ts" ! tsdemux name=demux \
demux. ! queue ! decodebin ! videorate ! videoscale ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location="some_file-video.mp4" 
demux. ! queue ! meta/x-klv ! filesink location="some_file.txt"
```

The command doesn't work. It just gets stuck after the following message on the terminal;

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
```

and, the size text and video files is 0 bytes.

An example .ts file can be found at(this file hasn't been uploaded and created by me, it is part of data for some code on github(https://gist.github.com/All4Gis/509fbe06ce53a0885744d16595811e6f)):  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AIbCGTqjk8NgA4R818pGSvU1UCcm-lib?usp=sharing

Thank you for helping! Cheers. :)

**Edit:**

I realised that there can be some confusion. The files in the link above were just used to create the .ts file.

The .ts file I am using, is available directly in either of the links below:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t-u8rnEE2MftWQkS1q3UB-J3ogXBr3p9?usp=sharing

https://easyupload.io/xufeny

Comment: I see the same issue with your MISB.ts file.  The embedded data is of "Asynchronous" format, which should work with GstTsDemux.  But, it has some variant causing issues.  Your pipeline works OK with other Async KLV TS files I have.

Comment: Digging deeper into your MISB.ts file.  The KLV data is in large bursts of about 200+ contiguous KLV data TS pkts sections separated by couple seconds with PCR discontinuities.  Then encapsulated in PES pkts with data between the header and the KLV contents that I don't recognize.  The video plays because a player will discard the klv data PIDs. ... Anyway, I'm investigating this for my own pipeline stability.  But, it looks like your MISB.ts file might be an abnormal stream.  More analysis is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are using (MISB.ts) presumably carries Asynchronous KLV `stream_id=0xBD, stream_type=0x06`. But it seems odd.  There are 200+ or so continuous KLV packets in a burst. Often, the KLV data flows over from the previous PES Pkt (highlighted red in the attached pic - original) into the new PES Pkt. Then a new KLV block is started (orange header, white payload). And repeat. I think this segmentation is not correct.

[image: Original KLV Data Layout]

I edited a few packets the way I think they should be.  Note, there is not more overflow of klv data (red highlight) between PES header and KLV header.

[image: Fixed KLV Data Layout]

I have also found I do not need multiqueue.  This pipeline works well for me on valid streams with *Asynchronous* KLV.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="MISB.ts" ! tsdemux name=demux   demux. ! queue ! video/x-h264 ! filesink location="/tmp/video.ts"   demux. ! queue ! meta/x-klv ! filesink location="/tmp/klv.ts"
```

Note: current gstreamer tsdemux does **not** support *Synchronous* KLV.

Regarding your demux pipeline and the KLV data not in-sync with the video:  Asynchronous KLV is aligned by in-stream proximity, not PTS.  It looks like the KLV embedding is clumped in large bursts. It is not spread out evenly. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems if we use Gstreamer's `multiqueue` element, instead of `queue`, the files are being created.

I tried the following based on a suggestion from a commenter on another website I had posted the question on:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="MISB.ts" ! tsdemux name=demux \
demux. ! multiqueue name=mq ! decodebin ! videorate ! videoscale ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! mp4mux ! filesink location="some_file-video.mp4" \
demux. ! mq. mq. ! meta/x-klv ! filesink location="some_file-KLV.txt"
```

But, the KLV data and frames are still not in sync. I need the KLV data corresponding to each frame.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One note on your pipelines, you are using an mp4 container, which requires the file header to be written with final size.  So, is it caching?

In my case I'm trying to get mpegtsmux and ts output which is a streaming format.

Comment: @Wayne thanks for responding. How do I check whether it is caching or not?

Comment: Actually, unlike ffmpeg, I don't think gstreamer uses file extension for anything.  So, disregard what I said about caching.  However, I've looked deeper into the stream, and it has issues (I think).  See my posted answer.